# SQL select user grouped by ip and select all other users with the same ips in one table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

How should the SQL SELECT query look like if I want to select definite user (i.e. WHERE username='peter') GROUP all rows BY ip and SELECT all other user that have same IPs?

This is a table's content with fields: id, ip, username

1 | 192.0.0.1 | peter
2 | 192.0.0.1 | jack
3 | 192.0.0.2 | peter
4 | 192.0.0.3 | justin
5 | 192.0.0.2 | justin

Executing necessary SQL SELECT query should select like this (with WHERE username='peter'):

2 | 192.0.0.1 | jack
5 | 192.0.0.2 | justin

That is SELECT query that has selected rows of usernames, who has the same IPs with the target username 'peter'.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE ip_address IN (SELECT ip_address
                     FROM your_table
                     WHERE user_name = 'peter')
    AND user_name <> 'peter'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE ip_address IN (SELECT ip_address
                     FROM your_table
                     WHERE user_name = 'peter');
```

Comment: Almost. You need to add another filter to remove the matches for 'peter' themselves.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name trying this SELECT user FROM entrances WHERE ip IN (SELECT ip FROM entrances WHERE user = 'peter') AND user <> 'peter' the SQL query takes about 30 seconds for executing with total 2850 rows inside the table. Sometimes it's just hangs up... (((

Comment: @ilnur777: Do you have an index on the IP and/or the user_name column?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually last query is that I have on my SQL. I don't have index in ip field. I guess it doesn't work on mysql at all. What can be the reason?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I put index on ip field and it began working. Thank you! :-)

Comment: @ilnur777: an index shouldn't change it from "not working" to "working". Only from "slow" to "fast"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM iptable t1
  INNER JOIN iptable t2 ON t1.ip = t2.ip AND t1.username <> t2.username
WHERE t2.username = 'peter'
```